# Batch scripting: Find pattern in string

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, pattern-matching

I have a for loop that gives me access to filenames in a folder, and I need to check that filename to see if it contains a string.

For example, filename: 'C:\Temp\hello.cs'
Pattern to find: 'C:\Temp\h'

The pseudocode for this is

```
IF filename.Contains(pattern) then
    // DO SOMETHING
END IF
```

I tried this:

```
%%i|find %pattern% >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo "Pattern matched"
```

But it just opened the file as if I'd double-clicked on the file.

Comment: You forgot the echo: `echo %%i|find...`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys but I found this worked:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set pattern=name

for .... do (
    Set filenameStr=%%i
    Set patternReplaced=!filenameStr:%pattern%=?!

    If Not !patternReplaced! == !filenameStr! echo "contains pattern"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_fileproperties.php) is a great resource for solving DOS/Batch file problems like this.  From what I'm seeing, something like this might work for you:

```
ECHO OFF

FOR %%A IN (C:\Temp\h*) DO (
    ECHO ---
    ECHO Pattern matched
    ECHO Name in 8.3 notation : %%~snA
    ECHO Fully Qualified Path : %%~fA
)
```

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, check the "[How To](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/bht.php)" section to see some other soutions.